# How to save a coordinate list after app is tombstoned?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, coordinates, tombstoning

I have a list of coordinates saved in a map class that are manipulated to draw a route between the points, but I'm not sure how to save these points when the application is closed and then reopened.

This is how I currently save the points within the app in the `OnNavigatedTo()`, the points and markers aren't lost as long as I don't close it. But how do I save these coordinates after I close the app?

I'm guessing I should save them in the `OnNavigatedFrom` but I tried saving the coordinate list here and the markers don't show when I repopen the app.

```
//save the coordinates to a list
mycoord.Add(new GeoCoordinate(MyGeoPosition.Latitude, MyGeoPosition.Longitude));

if (mycoord.Count == 2)
{
  //call route method when coord list equal to two.
  GetRoute();
}
```

Comment: How to preserve and restore app state for Windows Phone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save a list of coordinates to isolated storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563502/how-to-save-a-list-of-coordinates-to-isolated-storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this that is customizable would be to create a custom object and serialize it to the phone's storage using [EZ_Iso.dll](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2)

Here's an example

```
//Your custom GeoCoord container
[DataContractAttribute]
public class GeoCoordContainer{
  [DataMember]
  public double lat = 0;

  [DataMember]
  public double lon = 0;

  public GeoCoordContainer(Double lat, Double lon){
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
  }
}


//Then in your Navigated from method
  GeoCoordContainer cont = new GeoCoordContainer(MyGeoPosition.Lattitude,MyGeoPosition.Longitued);

  //Now save it to the storage using EZ_Iso
  EZ_Iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.SaveFile("MyLocation",cont);


 //To Retrieve it from storage 
  GeoCoordContainer cont = (GeoCoordContainer)EZ_Iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.GetFile("MyLocation",typeof(GeoCoordContainer));
```

You can find EZ_Iso.dll free here http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Comment: so I implemented this, just trying to figure out how to retrieve the `MyGeoPosition` from container, as I need to use it to call a draw method..Any ideas?

Comment: Its to hard to debug this here. Hit me up at amr@AnthonyRussell.info and we can discuss it further.

Answer (score 1):

Use Tombstone Helper http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
 {
this.SaveState(e);  // <- first line
 }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
this.RestoreState();  // <- second line
 }
```

Comment: check the State property of the page after calling SaveState to see what's it's saved , I doubt it will preserve your map, no idea !

Comment: post something in the discussions thread doubt you'll find the answer here, seem pretty helpful http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/discussions/

Answer (score 1):

You can create something simple like:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["latitude"] = MyGeoPosition.Latitude;
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["longitude"] = MyGeoPosition.Longitude;
```

Later access them as:

```
var lat=PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["latitude"];
var lng=PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["longitude"];
```

Also you can try:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
appSettings.Add("latitude", MyGeoPosition.Latitude.ToString());
```

Comment: I tried the following, save : `appSettings.Add("latitude", MyGeoPosition.Latitude.ToString());` and retrieve : `MyGeoPosition.Latitude = (double)appSettings["latitude"];` just trying to figure out where to retrieve in OnNavigatedTo() now

Comment: @BrianJ You're absolutely correct. Adding: ` if (appSettings.Contains("Latitude"))` will help check any exception in isolated storage settings.